# TestNG Configuration Failure excecution

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, testng

I was trying to run TestNG script via Selenium WD 3.6 Version
The script just need to browse to Facebook via Chrome Browser

```
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class FB {
     ChromeDriver driver= new ChromeDriver ();
     @BeforeTest
      public void beforeTest() {
         System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver.manage().window().maximize();

      } 

     @Test
     public void URL()
     {
         driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
}
}
```

I received the following error in console:

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.12.0
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot instantiate class Staging.FB
```

Please advise what i did wrong

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend changing your `driver` member type to `WebDriver`, then, instead of initializing at the class level, do so inside your `@BeforeTest` method.

If we look at the TestNG lifecycle, the `FB` class gets instantiated before the `@BeforeTest` method runs.  In order for that to happen, the `WebDriver` instance field needs to resolve.  Since you appear to be using a system property to set the location of the Chrome Driver executable, this initialization cannot take place without throwing an error (since this happens in `@BeforeTest`).  By moving the `WebDriver` initialization after the property declaration, initialization can run successfully.

So...

```
public class FB {
    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    public void beforeTest() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    // Then add your @Test method(s) here...
}
```

Comment: [RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.12.0
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest before

Comment: Can you please post the rest of the stack trace that accompanied that error message?

Comment: Looks like a Jar was missing. Now everything is ok and with your solution it works fine . Thank you very very much for your assitence as i really appreicate it